# Files not executing in any browser except IE

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am doing a simple dynamic web project in eclipse Luna with a set of JSP files and Tomcat web server. But problem is, whenever I run any of the JSP files, it gives an error "File name, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect" on all browsers except IE. I have searched a lot for this but I only got answers for maven projects. Can someone please provide a simpler solution ? Thanks in advance

Comment: The question was downvoted but no answer ?

Comment: Well, I guess the voter downvoted your question, because it is very unlikely to solve this problem without any code. The message mentions an incorrect syntax, but you're not showing us the mentioned line (or JSP file). So how could we help you here?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. It opens in IE. But its not working if I set the browser as Firefox or Chrome in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Solved :  We just need to change the settings in Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser and click on new and add our own browser(FF or chrome) by giving its file path. Then it works.